# How to send Json to Struts2?

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp, struts2

There is a Json object and I don't know how to get it in struts2,there are two arrays in it,how to transfer it to ArrayList in java?

[image]

```js
var params = {
        'goodsIdList':goodsIdList,
        'goodsCountList':goodsCountList
    }
    console.log(params);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "checkGoodsIsEnough",
        data: params,
        dataType:"json",
        async: true,
        success: alert("success"),
        error: function (jqXHR) {
            alert(jqXHR.status);
        }

    })
```

Comment: here is an example on how to do it: [struts2 and json example](https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-and-json-example/)

Comment: i want to konw how to get json object in struts2 sended by ajax,not send json object to ajax by struts

Answer (score 2):

I will suppose that you have already added this config to your struts.xml to provide JSON format support :

```
<action name="checkGoodsIsEnough" class="ClassOf_CheckGoodsIsEnough">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
         <interceptor-ref name="json">
            <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
</action>
```

If this is the case, dont forget to convert your javascript object to JSON string format by using :

```
var JsonParams = JSON.stringify(params);
```

And then try to do the Post call as follow :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "checkGoodsIsEnough",
    data: JsonParams,
    dataType:"json",
    async: true,
    success: alert("success"),
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        alert(jqXHR.status);
    }

});
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Your answer helps me.The json object is right,but how to get it in struts2?

Comment: You must avoid implementing "ModelDriven" interface, and define

Comment: And define "attribute", "setter" and "getter" for each param in the request.

Comment: Here is a complete example of what you must do : http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/send-json-object-to-struts-2-action-by-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 1):

You need the [struts2-json-plugin](https://struts.apache.org/docs/json-plugin.html).

It serves two main purposes:

> **#1** - Converting **Java** objects **to JSON** through the **`json` result** (from Action to JSP);
>
> **#2** - Converting **Javascript** objects **to JSON** through the **`json` interceptor** (from JSP to Action).

While the first is automatic, for the second (that is what you want) you need to define an interceptor stack containing the `json` interceptor, for example:

```xml
<package name="myPackage" extends="json-default">
...
    <action name="myAction" class="foo.bar.MyAction">

        <interceptor-ref name="json"         /> <!-- #2 is here -->
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />

        <result name="success" type="json"> <!-- #1 is here -->
            <param name="root">myJavaObjectThatWillBecomeJson</param>
        </result>
        <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
    </action>
    ...
```

After confirming that it is working, you can (and should) define the interceptor stack once in the configuration, setting it as the default interceptor, instead of rewriting this configuration inside every action.

For the json Interceptor to run properly, the conditions are:

> - The "`content-type`" must be "`application/json`"
> - The JSON content must be well formed, see [json.org](http://json.org) for grammar.
> - Action must have a public "setter" method for fields that must be populated.
> - Supported types for population are: Primitives (int,long...String), Date, List, Map, Primitive Arrays, Other class
>   (more on this later), and Array of Other class.
> - Any object in JSON, that is to be populated inside a list, or a map, will be of type Map (mapping from properties to values), any
>   whole number will be of type Long, any decimal number will be of type
>   Double, and any array of type List.